# Dúvida python criaçao de modelo machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

Eu tenho uma dúvida na criação do meu modelo de machine learning. Eu quero criar um modelo que me preveja o `PSS_Stress`

```
columns = "ExamID;FinalGrade;PSS_Stress;StudyID;TotalQuestions;avg_durationperquestion;avg_tbd;decision_time_efficiency;good_decision_time_efficiency;maxduration;median_tbd;minduration;num_decisions_made;question_enter_count;ratio_decisions;ratio_good_decisions;totalduration;variance_tbd".split(";")
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
dfimp = df.fillna(df.mean())  

X = dfimp.drop(['PSS_Stress'], axis=1) 
Y=dfimp['PSS_Stress'] 
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size)

cart = DecisionTreeClassifier()
cart.fit(X_train, Y_train) 
score=cart.score(X_validation, Y_validation)
print(score)
```

A minha dúvida está na variável X. Eu nesta variável vou ter todas as features do meu dataset ou todas as features exepto a minha variavel target que neste caso é `PSS_Stress` que foi como fiz na imagem acima

Answer (score 1):

`X_train` terá todas as variáveis necessárias para prever o valor de `Y_train`. Se `Y_train` possui apenas a coluna `PSS_Stress`, então `X_train` terá todas as outras colunas do teu dataset, **exceto** `PSS_Stress`.

Afinal, não faz sentido utilizar `PSS_Stress` para prever ela mesma.